# jQuery html property...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright... My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="_content"></div>
```

And then, there is a method like this:

```
Main.LoadContent(source, target)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var s = '';
    reader.onload = function()
    {
        s = reader.result;
        var t = $(target).html;
        alert(t);
        t.html = s;
    }
    var f = new File([""], source);
    reader.readAsText(f);
}
```

Mind the 'alert(t)' line, it returns:

```
function ( value ) {
    return access( this, function( value ) {
        var elem = this[ 0 ] || {},
            i = 0,
            l = this.length;

        if ( value === undefined ) {
            return elem.nodeType === 1 ?
                elem.innerHTML.replace( rinlinejQuery, "" ) :
                undefined;
        }

        // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
        if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test( value ) &&
            ( support.htmlSerialize || !rnoshimcache.test( value )  ) &&
            ( support.leadingWhitespace || !rleadingWhitespace.test( value ) ) &&
            !wrapMap[ (rtagName.exec( value ) || [ "", "" ])[ 1 ].toLowerCase() ] ) {

            value = value.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" );

            try {
                for (; i < l; i++ ) {
                    // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
                    elem = this[i] || {};
                    if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                        jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );
                        elem.innerHTML = value;
                    }
                }

                elem = 0;

            // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
            } catch(e) {}
        }

        if ( elem ) {
            this.empty().append( value );
        }
    }, null, value, arguments.length );
}
```

The call to Main.LoadContent looks like this:

```
Main.LoadContent('start.htf', '#_content');
```

What's my sublime stupidity come to here...???

Comment: [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a function, not a property.

Comment: `var t = $(target).html;` wut

Comment: `var t = $(target).html;` should be `var t = $(target).html();`

Comment: `t.html = s;` wut

Comment: might help if you read the docs : http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a function... put the s variable inside of the function to set the HTML... see what that gets you. Example:

```
     Main.LoadContent(source, target)
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var s = '';
            reader.onload = function()
            {
                s = reader.result;
                var t = $(target).html();
                alert(t);
                //t.html(s);
                $(target).html(s);

            }
            var f = new File([""], source);
            reader.readAsText(f);
        }
```